# Getting a MySQL query to be found based on which item is selected in the listbox

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox

Okay I have the following code. It does everything I want except for this one thing. Where you see the query:

```
 string query1 = "UPDATE caregiverdatabse SET child1 = NULL WHERE id='" + selectedCaregiver + "'";
```

This only lets me set the "child1" column in the row to null. I would like for it to be able to go through child1, child2, child3, child4, or child5 (Without having to code it in directly like it is now).
The code ahead of it:

```
string currentChildIndex = "";
string spotOfChange = "";
int index;
string item;
foreach (int i in childrenListBoxDisp.SelectedIndices)
{
    item = childrenListBoxDisp.Items[i].ToString();
}
```

allows me to delete only the first selected item from the childrenListBoxDisp which is linked to the MySQL database and only if it is in the child1 column. I would like it to be able to delete any of the childX columns based on which item it is selected on. It is all in the query I beleive. Help is appreciated!!

Rest of the code:

```
            DialogResult dialogResult = 
                    MessageBox.Show("You are about to remove " + item + 
                    " person from the selected caregiver. Continue?", "Are you sure?",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=" + server +
                    ";" + "Port=" + port + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" 
                    + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Password=" + password + ";");
                connection.Open();

                string query1 = "UPDATE caregiverdatabse SET child1 = NULL WHERE id='"
                                     + selectedCaregiver + "'";
                childrenListBoxDisp.Items.Clear();
                assignNamesToChildList();
                Console.WriteLine("Did we get here , clearing list");
                using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query1, connection))
                {
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
```

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your goal. Is `item` supposed to become the X in `childX`?

Comment: Show a partial schema for what you're updating to.

Comment: Are `child2, child3, child4, or child5` columns in your table?  If so, you have some database design issues that should be addressed.  Read up on database normalization.  Also, it looks like you have a SQL Injection vulnerability in your code.  Read up on parameterization.

Comment: @KyleG. childX is where the child is currently located. Right now all the query allows me to do is manually code in which childX slot to remove. So basically yes item is the child at childrenListBoxDisp.Items[i] (selected child on the listbox).

Comment: @AbeMiessler yes, I do have to look into that still.

Comment: You could try something simple (although not very elegant) like `string query1 = "UPDATE caregiverdatabse SET child" + item + " = NULL WHERE id='" + selectedCaregiver + "'";` assuming `item` returns a value that makes sense in your column naming scheme.

Comment: @KyleG. I added in an extra loop while using and modding a bit of this code too and figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Consider using "answer your own question" so anyone who comes across this in the future will know what to do :)